# When I update the state variable of child component ,why it cause infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bbekrh?file=src%2FStaffManagement.js).

I am creating a header detail page, I want to show the first staff detail in the staff detail table.

Unfortunately, I am facing a problem which is strange.

In order to get data from the server, I need to use the `useEffect` hook, so I have to save data to a state variable (i.e. `staffData`) in App.js, and then submit it to the `StaffManagement` component.

In order to show the first staff detail in the staff detail table, I create a state variable `staffDetail` in the `StaffManagement` component.

When I set a value to the state variable `staffDetail`, that means the following statement,

```
setStaffDetail(staff);
```

The browser shows the following message:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I have no `useEffect` hook in the `StaffManagement` component, why it causes an infinite loop?

Comment: Because `count===0` is always `true` and when `setStaffDetail` is called it re-renders and causes infinite loop

Comment: I added  'count++` after the `setStaffDetail` statement, however, it does not help.

Comment: Made a bunch of changes here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sbu6qb?file=src%2FStaffManagement.js

Answer (score 0):

Because It `setStaffDetail` every render. When `setStaffDetail` call it trigger render, then it `setStaffDetail`...You need wrap it in a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    for (const [staffId, staff] of Object.entries(staffData)) {
      staffList.push(
        <tr key={staffId}>
          <td>{staff.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );
      if (count === 0) {
        setStaffDetail(staff);
      }
    }
}, [staffData]);
```

Another way to solve that is use `useRef`

```
const count = useRef(0);


for (const [staffId, staff] of Object.entries(staffData)) {
    staffList.push(
      <tr key={staffId}>
        <td>{staff.name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
    if (count.current === 0) {
      count.current++;
      setStaffDetail(staff);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need count variable to updateyour array data.
Try to use useEffect, my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uburt9?file=src%2FStaffManagement.js)

```
      let staffData = props.staffData;
      const [staffList, setStaffList] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        const list = [];
        for (const [staffId, staff] of Object.entries(staffData)) {
          list.push(
            <tr key={staffId}>
              <td>{staff.name}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        }
        setStaffList(list);
      }, []);
```

Comment: The variable `count` is for setting the first `staff`  to the state variable `staffDetail`.

Comment: oh sorry I got it. In this case, just point to staffList[0] for a default value if staffList.length return true.